# Cumulative total of file column in another column

Tags: awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a file with 2 columns separated by space delimiter:

```
Location 5
AdministrativeRegion 2
Person 3
Athlete 4
FloweringPlant 8
Film 1
Actor 2
```

I want to have a cumulative total of numbers of second column in a third column like:

```
Location 5 5
AdministrativeRegion 2 7
Person 3 10
Athlete 4 14
FloweringPlant 8 22
Film 1 23
Actor 2 25
```

I know this can be achieved with `awk`

With something similar to: `awk '{total += $0; $0 = total}1'`

But I want the result in a new column.

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Location 5
AdministrativeRegion 2
Person 3
Athlete 4
FloweringPlant 8
Film 1
Actor 2
```

then

```
{total+=$2;print $0,total}
```

output

```
Location 5 5
AdministrativeRegion 2 7
Person 3 10
Athlete 4 14
FloweringPlant 8 22
Film 1 23
Actor 2 25
```

Explanation: In each line increase (`+=`) `total` by value from 2nd column (`$2`) then `print` whole line as is (`$0`) followed by current `total`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*